# ExtJS 4.2.0 RowExpander with load data dynamic

Tags: javascript, plugins, extjs

I wanna use the ExtJs plugin "RowExpander", but, I would load the data when the event expandbody is fired.
I've try this code, but I don't know how set the content of the rwoBody Expanded:

```
this.GridPrincipal.getView().addListener('expandbody', function (rowNode, record, expandRow, eOpts) {


        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'getData/' + record.get('id'),
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (result, request) {
            // retrive the data
            var jsonData = Ext.util.JSON.decode(result.responseText);
            //code to change the text of the RowBody
                            //....
            },
            failure: function (result, request) {
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Failed', result.responseText);
            return false;
            }
            });



    });
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

One solution with which you can render any data or even other components into the expander is to assign it a div.

```
plugins: [{
        ptype: 'rowexpander',
        rowBodyTpl: ['<div id="ux-row-expander-box-{id}"></div>'],
        expandOnRender: true,
        expandOnDblClick: true
    }]
```

where 'id' is the id field of your store.

next on expandbody event, you can fetch your data using e.g. Ajax request and then render a panel or grid etc. containing the data into this div using the renderTo config.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. My solution is:

```
Ext.get(expandRow).setHTML('New Text');
```

I will be interested to hear if there is a better way.